# Is there any way to hide all admin notification for non admin users in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there any way to all hide admin notification for non-admin users.

I have used below code but it will hide only update notification but I need to hide all notification

```
 function hide_update_notice_to_all_but_admin_users()
    {
        if (!current_user_can('update_core')) {
            remove_action( 'admin_notices', 'update_nag', 3 );
        }
    }
    add_action( 'admin_head', 'hide_update_notice_to_all_but_admin_users', 1 );
```

I'm also want to hide these type of notifications.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert the following code on your functions.php file of your active theme. This code may disable all the updates notifications regarding plugins, themes & WordPress completely.

```
function remove_core_updates(){
    global $wp_version;
    return(object) array('last_checked'=> time(),'version_checked'=> $wp_version,);
}
add_filter('pre_site_transient_update_core','remove_core_updates');
add_filter('pre_site_transient_update_plugins','remove_core_updates');
add_filter('pre_site_transient_update_themes','remove_core_updates');
```

I hope that this code works fine.